# How change font JPaint with firemonkey?

Tags: java, android, firemonkey

I need to print a PDF file using `firemonkey` with `JPdfDocument`;

I've written the code below its work, but don't change the font: 
    [Here is the documentation link](https://github.com/AlessandroMartini/Delphi-Android-GeraPDF)

```
procedure TForm1.btGerarPDFClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   Document: JPdfDocument;
   PageInfo: JPdfDocument_PageInfo;
   Page: JPdfDocument_Page;
   Canvas: JCanvas;
   Paint: JPaint;
   Recto: JRect;
   Rect: JRect;
   FileName: string;
   OutputStream: JFileOutputStream;
   Intent: JIntent;

   begin
       // create Pdf document
       Document := TJPdfDocument.JavaClass.init;
       try
            // create page  1
            PageInfo := TJPageInfo_Builder.JavaClass.init(100, 100, 1).create;
            Page := Document.startPage(PageInfo);

            Canvas := Page.getCanvas;
            Paint := TJPaint.JavaClass.init;

            Paint.setARGB($FF, 0, 0, $FF);

           // I need to change the font to: Courier New, Size 9

           Canvas.drawText(StringToJString('Courier New 9'), 10, 50, Paint);

          // I need to change the font to: Courier New, Size 14

          Canvas.drawText(StringToJString('Courier 14'), 10, 50, Paint);

         Document.finishPage(Page);

        // write PDF document to file
        FileName := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetSharedDocumentsPath, 'demo.pdf');
          OutputStream := TJFileOutputStream.JavaClass.init
         (StringToJString(FileName));
           try
             Document.writeTo(OutputStream);
           finally
             OutputStream.close;
        end;
   finally
      Document.close;
   end;

   // start PDF viewer
      Intent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init;
      Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW);
      Intent.setDataAndType(FileNameToUri(FileName),
      StringToJString('application/pdf'));
      Intent.setFlags(TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY or
      TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
      SharedActivity.StartActivity(Intent);
   end;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Paint.setARGB($FF, 0, 0, 0); // color
paint.setFakeBoldText(true);// font bol
Paint.setTextSize(16); // font size
Paint.setFontFeatureSettings(StringToJString('Segoe Script')); //font name
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.